# Page viewer web part shows a blank page

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, 2016, iframe

I added a page viewer web part in SharePoint page , add the page link ,save and close, no errors, it shows a blank page !!

PS: The page url browsed in the browser normally, I also enabled the iframe in the site settings,

Any thoughts!

Comment: Is that happening you with all browsers? URL is same domain as SP or different? Is a HTTPS URL inside a HTTP SP?

Comment: Is the URL pointing to a page you created in a web site, or a public site. Many public sites include JavaScript "frame buster" routines that detect IFrames and then redirect, or display an alternate output.  What do you see when you right-click inside of the Page Viewer web part and click click View Source?

Comment: Use F12 developer tools to see if there are any errors. Delete other web parts on the page, just leave page viewer web part on the page. Check if it is caused by the conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue usually occurs in case you have edited your page and added the Page Viewer Web Part using **Google Chrome**!

In Google Chrome, the blank page inside the `Page Viewer Web Part` means

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame!

To make sure that, try to open the same page in **Internet Explorer** and you will get

[image]

**So How to solve this issue?**

- Go to Site Collection Settings > Site Collection Administration > HTML Field Security
- Check `Permit contributors to insert iframes from any external domain into pages on this site.`

[image]

- Go back to your page and check if the Page URL has been rendered inside the Page Viewer web part or not!

**In case,** the issue still persists that means **the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.**

Comment: OP stated in question that they enabled iframe in site settings

Comment: Please, Read the answer carefully and you will know I replied to this point! he talks about the blank page! so I provide detail answer!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Page Viewer web part just use an iframe in the 'embed code' web part:

```
<iframe src="https://www.sitename.com/page" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried this!

Comment: Yes. Resolved the same issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had flowcharts in PDF format in the Sharepoint Page Viewer web part. They were visible in Edge but blank in Chrome. This will probably only help those that are displaying PDFs as a webpage.

[image: Edit web part Page Viewer]

- Google Chrome > Settings > Privacy & Security > Site Settings
- Scroll to the bottom and expand Additional Content Settings
- Additional Content Settings > PDF
- Uncheck 'Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome'

[image: Uncheck download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome]

Hope this helps, it worked for me.